# Given an integer, remove three digits to make the smallest integer

Tags: combinatorics

Suppose you have an integer, for example 112003000215554.

1. You are asked to remove three digits to make the number the smallest it could be.
2. You are asked to put arithmetic operators between the digits to create the largest possible number.

My question is: What is the general strategy for this type of problem (it seems that the strategy is just trial and error). This sort of problem seems to appear in competitions.

Comment: Why the downvotes? It is a serious question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that the final integer will have its left-most digit being one of the four first digits of the given number.  (See why?)

Remove 0 or 1 or 2 or 3 digits to leave the remaining leading (left-most) digit as small as possible among the four possibilities.

Use any remaining 1 or 2 or 3 removal(s) to leave the remaining (next left-most) digit as small as possible.

Use any remaining removal to leave the remaining (next to next left-most) digit as small as possible.

Thus:  for your example, 112003000215554, remove the three left-most digits to produce:  003000215554 = 3000215554.

Formalized as an algorithm:

Given INPUT string...

1. Identify the location of the left-most lowest digit in the first four (left-most) of INPUT;  call that location dmin.
2. Delete the minimum number of digits to the left of dmin.  (Thus the digit in dmin is the leading digit in the developing OUTPUT.). Call that minimum number of digits removed MINdigits.
3. Identify the location of the left-most lowest-value digit among the 2nd through 2+(3 - MINdigits) digits of the current candidate OUTPUT.
4. Delete the minimum number of digits of the current 2nd through 2+(3 - MINdigits).
5. Repeat, as above, until all three allotted digits have been used.

Comment: The author of the problem should have specified whether leading zeros are allowed.  If they are not, $003000215554$ is not an acceptable answer.

Comment: I am not the author of this problem and it does not state of leading zeros are allowed or not.